# Update XML nodevalue with C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have an XML as below

```
<ROOT>
  <Device>
    <host>localhost</host>
    <Port>52000</Port>
  </Device>
  <DeviceHost>
    <Server>Server.exe</Server>
    <Port>81</Port>
  </DeviceHost>
  <Settings>
<Flag1>100</Flag1>
<Flag2>2000</Flag2>
  </Settings>
</ROOT>
```

How can I update the `Flag1` and `Flag2` to `200` and `4000` respectively without changing other values using VC++?

I have two function wrote using api MSXML.

```
 doc.LoadXml(Data);//for loading the xml data
 doc.Save(FilePath);//for saving the xml data
```

But my issue is before saving how can i update two node values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to get the correct node by calling `getElementsByTagName` (which should return a NodeList containing one item) and then call `put_nodeValue` to write the value -- there are some MSDN samples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd893253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd892262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

EDIT: you should also be able to use `doc.selectSingleNode("/ROOT/Flag1", &pNode)` as per [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757846%28VS.85%29.aspx)